# How to make amazon banner responsive?

Tags: javascript

I'm planning to put ads on my website. It is from amazon, I just want it to be responsive, and set up that setting. But still not responsive. Please see my code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        amzn_assoc_placement = "adunit0";
        amzn_assoc_search_bar = "true";
        amzn_assoc_tracking_id = "my-tracking-id";
        amzn_assoc_ad_mode = "manual";
        amzn_assoc_ad_type = "smart";
        amzn_assoc_isresponsive = "true";
        amzn_assoc_marketplace = "amazon";
        amzn_assoc_region = "US";
        // amzn_assoc_title = "My Amazon Picks";
        amzn_assoc_linkid = "1dd3cc861d15aa94zd15335vxca38a5q";
        amzn_assoc_asins = "T33BC0SPIQ,B0000FGZCB,B01G72LG3W,B015YHO567";
</script>
<script src="//z-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/onejs?MarketPlace=US"></script>
```

Comment: I couldn't get it to show an actual add, error 500 but I suppose wrapping resulting DOM element in custom div with adjusted style will work..